# SailsJs Response (res) life Cycle

Tags: node.js, api, sails.js, hook, interceptor

Is there a way to hook up a function or task to sails response , before emitting the functions, like for example , i have several `res.ok(object_output)`; based on some conditions and in separate controllers , i want to intercept each res.ok (just like **policies**) to do something before returning the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in `api/responses/ok.js`.

Comment: nice thanks. is there no other way instead of tempering with  sailsjs codes or something for maintenance sake

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way to do it. Might be possible with some event related to request lifecycle or middleware but haven't tried it. On other note, it is fine to tweak with `ok.js` it is not in Sails node module, it is part of project generated by Sails.